# Angular-6 can't hide app header and footer in Sign in page and signup page

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I'm beginner for the Angular-6 , I created the project  then I have a small issue in `Create Account` page & `Sign in page` showing the app-header and app-footer. but i don't want to show that page on app-header & app-footer i want to know how to do that correctly display on `apirequest page` .

That is my code part

**app-routes.ts**

```
export const Approutes: Routes = [
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/signup', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
      {path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent},
      {path: 'forgotpassword', component: ForgotpasswordComponent},
      {path: 'apirequest', component: ApirequestComponent},
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this video https://youtu.be/LaIAHOSKHCQ?t=126 It contains all you need to solve your issue

Comment: @yurzui Sir, Thanks for the your valuable guidance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `app.component.ts` you could subscribe to the `Router.events`.

```js
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
  private router: Router,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events
    .subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.headerFooter = (event.url !== '/login')
      }
    });
}
```

```
<app-header *ngIf="headerFooter"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="headerFooter"></app-footer>
```

If the `event.url` is not equal to `/login` then you show the elements, otherwise you hide them. You can run the check against any url path you want to hide/show the header/footer on, just update the conditional statement.

Comment: Sir, Wheres to put that code part. `app.component.ts` or `app.routing.ts`

Comment: `app.component.ts`

Comment: You need to define `headerFooter` in the component.

Comment: How can I check for other routes where I don't want to show header like some other public pages ? I tried to use || operator with this.headerFooter = (event.url !== '/login') but it say linter always says it will always be true, and gives error.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest for you to create two different components and look at [Angular Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) for your project. This will help you guarantee that after loggin in your application your user would not be able to go back to "/login".

It would look like

```
App/
|
|– login/
|– home/
```

And on your guard the logic will be something like

```
canActivate() {
 if (user) {
  return true;
 } else router.navigateByURL('login');
}
```

This way you can separate your application life cycle and only use footer and header where you want them to be :)

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks for the help

Comment: You’re welcome! Just watch out for ngIf since they are heavy for your browser :)